# Get-ADGroup where there are more than 500 members (including nested)

Tags: powershell, count, active-directory

I'm trying to run a PowerShell query to bring back groups with more than 500 members in it.

I've tried to run a measure statement & count -gt 500

```bsh
Get-ADGroup  -Filter {name -like "Distribution*"} -Properties * |
    measure |
    where count -gt 100 |
    select name
```

I'd like this to bring back just group names that have > 500 members in it.

Comment: Use `Get-ADGroupMember` to get the members of a group. As far as I can tell, your script is just finding any group with the word "Distribution" in it.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should've made it more clear. I just require the name of the group. 

The convention is as below:

Distribution-product
Distribution-team1
Distribution-team2

Comment: `Get-ADGroup` should only return the group names. It won't return the number of members in it. You need to combine the results of `Get-ADGroup` with `Get-ADGroupMember` to get the number of members in an AD group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be especially quick but you can run this to get an output of each group and a count of how many members there are. The where statement at the end will only output those with more than or equal to 500 members.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | select Name, @{n="Count";e={(Get-ADGroupMember $_.samaccountname -Recursive).count}} | ? Count -ge 500
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Works very well

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
Get-ADGroup  -Filter {name -like "Distribution*"} -Properties * | where {$($_.members.count) -GE 500} | select Name
```